# FreeIPA subject name encoding mismatch when renewing certificate

Tags: windows, certificate, certificate-authority, freeipa, utf-8

When reading this question and answer, it seems this should be possible but I need a little more help understanding the answer.

[Is there a way to change the string format for an existing CSR "Country Code" field from UTF8 to Printable String?](https://serverfault.com/questions/422639/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-string-format-for-an-existing-csr-country-code-fi#_=)_

I'm going the opposite way, PRINTABLESTRING to UTF8.  I don't understand how to locate the correct value to edit, could someone expand on that for me?  Why are the hex values listed vertically like that, is that how I should be looking for them?  The hex editor I'm using is called Hexer as I'm familiar with vi movements (but not Hexer itself).

https://devel.ringlet.net/editors/hexer/

**Background**

I'm renewing a certificate in FreeIPA.  The Certificate Authority is Windows.  I've got as far as forcing Windows to issue our certificate with the subject name in UTF8 by making sure it is issued via the command line on Windows instead of the GUI.

But now it is complaining about the Certificate Authority chain:

```
ipa-cacert-manage renew --external-cert-file=./freeipaca-windows-commandline.pem --external-cert-file=./cachain.pem

Importing the renewed CA certificate, please wait
CA certificate chain in ./freeipaca-windows-commandline.pem, ./cachain.pem is incomplete: missing certificate with subject 'CN=example.com ICA Windows-CA,DC=example,DC=com'
```

I think that it is because the chain has the commonName field as PRINTABLESTRING instead of UTF8. This is the same problem we had with the subject field of the certificate until we used the Windows command line to issue the cert instead:

```
# openssl x509 -in cachain.pem -subject -issuer -nameopt multiline,show_type -noout
subject=
    domainComponent           = IA5STRING:com
    domainComponent           = IA5STRING:example
    domainComponent           = IA5STRING:internal
    commonName                = PRINTABLESTRING:internal.example.com ICA Windows-CA2
issuer=
    commonName                = PRINTABLESTRING:example.com Root CA Windows-CA1
```

Or maybe there is an even simpler way to get around this?

---

**Update**

Looks like I didn't solve the original problem by using the command line to issue the cert on Windows after all.  FreeIPA 4.6.8 still thinks there is a problem.

```
ipa-cacert-manage renew --external-cert-file=./cert_and_chain.pem
Importing the renewed CA certificate, please wait
Subject name encoding mismatch (visit http://www.freeipa.org/page/Troubleshooting for troubleshooting guide)
The ipa-cacert-manage command failed.
```

```
# openssl x509 -in cert_and_chain.pem -subject -issuer -nameopt multiline,show_type -noout 
subject=
    organizationName          = PRINTABLESTRING:EXAMPLE.NET
    commonName                = PRINTABLESTRING:Certificate Authority
issuer=
    domainComponent           = IA5STRING:com
    domainComponent           = IA5STRING:example
    commonName                = PRINTABLESTRING:example.com ICA Windows-CA
```

Comment: The certificate will ***not*** be valid anymore if you change it. That's kinda the point of certificates; they're supposed to be immutable.

Comment: Apart from that it's highly unlikely that the problem is the encoding. That CN does not contain any special chars.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need/want to do this. Could you expand on that aspect?

Comment: `I've got as far as forcing Windows to issue our certificate with the subject name in UTF8` What happens with a certificate that is issued normally?

Comment: `Sections 4.1.2.4 [issuer] and 4.1.2.6 [subject] incorporate the conditions for  continued use of legacy text encoding schemes that were
 specified in [RFC4630].  Where in use by an established PKI,
 transition to UTF8String could cause denial of service based on name chaining failures or incorrect processing of name
 constraints.` [page 4] https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt

Comment: The certificate must use the same encoding as the issuer.  This will work as it does for all other implementations. If it doesn't work for you, get another issuer. It's a certificate, not a year long project.

Comment: Also according to the following article eight years ago in 2015, this is known issue in FreeIPA. It was closed as "errata". Looks like they changed the attributes on the AD CA to be compatible with FreeIPA. 
 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1169591

Comment: Yeah, no matter what we do to the Window CA, it still won't produce a cert with UTF8 encoding.

We're going to give up, we'll use something else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know (and I don't even *want* to know) the specifics.

Suffice is to say, you can't change anything in a certificate after it has been issued.

That's the whole purpose of a certificate.